# Link to function with the same name in a different namespace

Tags: doxygen

I have two functions with the same name in a different namespace:

```cpp
xt::xtensor<double, 2> GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::I4d();
```

and

```cpp
template <class T>
void GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::pointer::I4d(T* A);
```

In the documentation of `GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::pointer::I4d` I want to link to `GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::I4d`. But **how do I do that**?

I tried in the docstring of `GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::pointer::I4d`:

- `I4d()`
- `Cartesiand2d::I4d()`
- `GMatTensor::Cartesiand2d::I4d()`

In each case a link is produced, but always to `GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::pointer::I4d` and not to the intended `GMatTensor::Cartesian2d::I4d`

---

Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
/**
\file mylib.h
*/

namespace GMatTensor {
namespace Cartesian2d {

/**
Lorem ipsum.

\return [2, 2, 2, 2] array.
*/
inline xt::xtensor<double, 4> I4d();

namespace pointer {

    /**
    See Cartesian2d::I4d()

    \param ret output 2nd order tensor
    */
    template <class T>
    inline void I4d(T* ret);

} // namespace pointer
} // namespace Cartesian2d
} // namespace GMatTensor
```

with `Doxyfile`

```
IMPUT = .
```

(I ran with doxygen 1.9.1)

---

**Edit** I filed a bug report: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8403

Comment: Which version of doxygen?  Please also add a small example with which we can test / reproduce the problem.

Comment: @albert The version of doxygen is 1.9.1. I will try to make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @albert I've edited to include a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I did some test and see that the reference goes into the "namespace pointer" and not to the inline function. I did some further tests but I don't see a solution, probably best to create an issue in the github repository.

Comment: @albert Thanks a lot. Too bad.. I will open an issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @albert If it would work, what would you say that the correct syntax would be?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the syntax but probably something like the used `Cartesian2d::I4d()` or `GMatTensor::Cartesiand2d::I4d()`